# данные Сохраняется в базе в том же строке

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, fileupload

Здравствуйте писал программа который User может добавить несколько фотографии. Когда user добавляет фотографии, это фотки добавляются в базе в том же строке, то есть когда он выбирал допустим 2 фото и нажал добавить я этот момент поставил debug и следил шаг за шагом он сохраняет фото под номером один потом в том же строке добавляет фото под номером 2 в чем может быть причина?

> Код добавлении фотографии

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addAnswerPicture",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAnswerPicture(@ModelAttribute("answerPicture") AnswerPicture answerPicture,@RequestParam("pic") MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(imageUploadPath);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        String picName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
        File picture = new File("D:\\itBrainPictures\\" + picName);
        file.transferTo(picture);
        answerPicture.setImagePath(picName);
        answerPictureRepository.save(answerPicture);

    }

    return "redirect:/adminHome";
}
```

> redirect идет вот сюда

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/adminHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminController(ModelMap map) {
    map.addAttribute("newTask", new Task());
    map.addAttribute("newAnswer", new Answer());
    map.addAttribute("newAnswerPicture",new AnswerPicture());
    map.addAttribute("allTasks", taskRepository.findAll());
    map.addAttribute("allAnswers", answerRepository.findAll());
    return "adminHomes";
}
```

> JSP

```
<spring:form action="/addAnswerPicture" modelAttribute="newAnswerPicture" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<spring:select path="answer">
    <c:forEach items="${allAnswers}" var="answer">
        <option value="${answer.id}">${answer.timestamp}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</spring:select>
<input type="file" name="pic" multiple accept="pic/*"/>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
```

> Фотография из базы
>   [image: фотография из базы]

программа была написано на Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема может быть в том, что у вас один и тот же объект `answerPicture` перезаписывается несколько раз в цикле. Видимо его нужно создавать для каждого файла:

```
for (MultipartFile file : files) {
    AnswerPicture answerPicture = new AnswerPicture();
    String picName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + 
    file.getOriginalFilename();
    File picture = new File("D:\\itBrainPictures\\" + picName);
    file.transferTo(picture);
    answerPicture.setImagePath(picName);
    answerPictureRepository.save(answerPicture);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое